# Storm word count topology in production mode with single node instance in the cluster

Tags: apache-storm

When running storm word count topology in production mode, if we have only one single node instance in the cluster, Does it still create 3 instances of Workerprocesses if we specify

**config.setNumWorkers(3);**

As per my understanding each Worker process runs on separate JVM instance?. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in your supervisor node's storm.yaml (or the defaults here https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/1828a17e553927419d380203055803647aab2aa1/conf/defaults.yaml#L148), you will see the `supervisor.slots.ports` setting. This setting defines how many worker processeses (JVMs) your supervisor node can start, i.e. the maximum number of worker slots the supervisor offers.

The number of workers you set in the topology config specifies how many worker slots you would like the topology to run in.

For example, if your supervisor config is the default, it will start at most 4 workers, because there are 4 ports listed in `supervisor.slots.ports`. If you then submit your topology with `config.setNumWorkers(3)`, the supervisor will start 3 worker JVMs on the supervisor machine, occupying 3 of the 4 slots and leaving one slot free.